# PhantomJSDriver ignores local storage path

Tags: .net, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, local-storage

I am using PhantomJS with the .NET bindings in the latest stable version (nuGet). I am trying to have multiple instances of Phantom running at the same time. Everything works fine, but I the instances share the local storage underneath.

As far as I could understand this happens because all instances use the same folder to store their local storage data. I am trying to change this to a unique folder with the following code:

```
var phantomJsDriverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
phantomJsDriverService.LocalStoragePath = @"C:/temp/localStorage";
this.Driver = new PhantomJSDriver(phantomJsDriverService);
```

Phantom ignores the setting completely and keeps using the default folder. I tried several combinations, different slashes, different folders, permissions.. but non of them worked. Has anyone successfully used a different local storage path with Phantom?

Is there any other way to have multiple instances of Phantom running independently?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using phantomJS on linux x64 you can test this binary which has the localStoragePath fix included:
https://github.com/PatrickHuetter/phantomjs/releases/tag/1.9.8-fixedStoragePath

If you're using phantomjs on another operating system you could checkout my fork and compile it on your plattform.
https://github.com/PatrickHuetter/phantomjs/tree/localStoragePathFix

PhantomJS 2.0 already has this fix included, so you can go with the official binary if you're using the 2.0 version or newer.